# How to pass data to a later stage of a compose pipeline

Tags: functional-programming

If I have a bunch of functions which strictly chain together, then it's easy enough to use `compose` to combine them:

```
f1 : A -> B
f2 : B -> C
f3 : C -> D
pipe(f1, f2, f3) : A -> D
```

Often I find that things aren't quite so perfect, and the information contained in `A` is needed again in a later stage:

```
f1 : A -> B
f2 : B -> C
f3 : (A, C) -> D
```

How do I elegantly compose these functions? I feel like I want some kind of "stash" to tuck the `A` into a Pair or something, map `pipe(f1,f2)` over the second element and then I have everything ready for `f3`. I can't come up with a very elegant way of doing this though, and it feels like a common enough situation that there must be an estalished pattern!

As an concrete example, say I have a string and I want to return it if it has an even length, otherwise I want to return `none`.

```
f1 = len
f2 = mod(2)
f3 = (s, m) => m == 0 ? Just(s) : None
```

How do I compose these together?

Comment: On the occasions I've found the need to refer to `A` in `f3` (or similar), I've indeed returned some sort of tuple from `f2`. It's annoying and I do suspect there is a better way but I've not found one. I suppose you could have an intermediate function that wraps `f2` - let's call it `toTuple: X -> f -> (f(X), X)`, which returns the result *and* the input. You'd have to make it higher order enough to be able to specify *what* you want ferried in that tuple, so you can define a (modified)  `f1' : A -> (B, A)`, `f2' : (B, A) -> (C, A)` or similar. I'm not sure how you can do that generically.

Comment: The `toTuple` approach is what I've used before with reasonable success, but I feel like there must be a sufficiently generic solution too! With that you could do something like `pipe(toTuple(pipe(f1, f2)), f3)`

Answer (score 1):

The type of function composition doesn't allow this. I think that a lambda along with currying is straightforward and more explicit than passing a tuple type through the composition:

```js
const f1 = s => s.length;
const f2 = n => n % 2;
const f3 = s => m => m === 0 ? s : null;
const comp3 = f => g => h => x => f(g(h(x)));

const main = s => comp3(f3(s)) (f2) (f1) (s);

console.log(main("hallo"));
console.log(main("halloo"));
```

If you absolutely want it point free you can also utilize the fact that function composition may yield another function:

```js
const f1 = s => s.length;
const f2 = n => n % 2;
const f3 = s => m => m === 0 ? s : null;
const comp3 = f => g => h => x => f(g(h(x)));
const join = f => x => f(x) (x); // monadic join
const flip = f => y => x => f(x) (y);

const main = join(comp3(flip(f3)) (f2) (f1));

console.log(main("hallo"));
console.log(main("halloo"));
```

Pretty hard to read though.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate a little on my comment on the original question - I have found a way of achieving what I want in quite a (IMO) nice style. It still feels like I'm reinventing the wheel though, so another way to rephrase the original question might be: do you recognise the function signatures below?

```js
// stash :: A => [A,A]
const stash = x => [x, x];
// map :: (A => C) => [A,B] => [A,C]
const map = f => ([a, b]) => [a, f(b)];
// unstash :: ((A,B) => C) => [A,B] => C
const unstash = f => ([a, b]) => f(a, b);

const f1 = s => s.length;
const f2 = n => n % 2 === 0;
const f3 = (s, x) => x ? Option.some(s) : Option.none;

const getEvenName = 
  pipe(
    stash,
    map(f1),
    map(f2),
    unstash(f3)
  );

getEvenName("Lucy") // Some("Lucy");
getEvenName("Tom")  // None
```

Comment: `map` is just the functor instance of the pair tuple and `stash` is known as [`dupe`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%28a%2C+a%29&scope=set%3Astackage). `unstash` is usually called uncurry, but since you use Javascript's multi argument functions I'd probably call it `apply`. Still a lot of hassle to lift all involved functions into the pair context just to avoid a lambda...

Comment: Yes you're probably right that in a practical context a lambda will often be clearer, but it's good to understand the full range of solutions all the same!